# Code first migrations - how to rollback first migration

Tags: ef-code-first, rollback, entity-framework-migrations, database-versioning, database-deployment

Using code first migrations it is trivial to migrate to any given migration by using -TargetMigration [MigrationName].

But how do you rollback to before the first migration?  What migration do you target for that?  The first migration has a Down() just like the rest and the logic is sound - but how do I get it to execute via a update-database command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command:

```
Update-Database -Target 0
```